# Equivalence relations: showing $[b] \subseteq [a]$ while knowing $[a] \subseteq [b]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

> Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$ for two elements $a,b \in A$. Show that $[b]\subseteq [a]$.

In a previous section it was already proven that $[a]\subseteq [b]$. Can I just argue that by symmetry it must be true that $[b]\subseteq [a]$?

*EDIT*: Here's my attempt.

Assume $aRb$. Take any $t\in [a]$. Then $aRt$. By symmetry, $tRa$. Given $[a]\subseteq [b]$ then $t\in [b]$, and so $bRt$. Since $tRa$ and $bRt$, then $[a]=[b]$, therefore it follows $[b]\subseteq [a]$.

Comment: How was it proved that $[b] \subseteq [a]$? Also was it assumed that $aRb$ holds?

Comment: The first sentence "Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$ for two elements $a,b \in A$" doesn't make sense. A relation $\;R\;$ on $\;A\;$ is a subset of $\;A\times A\;$ and it is an equivalence relation if it fulfills some conditions. A relation is *not* "over some set for two elements" ...

Comment: This is page 643 of Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and  its Applications, 8th edition.

"Suppose $c\in [a]$. Then $aRc$. Because $aRb$ and $R$ is symmetric, we know that $bRa$. Furthermore, because $R$ is transitive and $bRa$ and $aRc$, it follows that $bRc$. Hence, $c\in [b]$. This shows that $[a] \subseteq [b]$. The proof that $[b]\subseteq [a]$ is similar, it is left as an exercise for the reader"

Comment: There is no need to prove $[b]\subseteq[a]$, as it has already been proven. This is because the previous part of the proof established that if $aRb$ then $[a]\subseteq[b]$ **for any** $a,b\in A$. In particular, this applies to the pair $(a',b')=(b,a)$ as well.

Comment: That's strange then. Not sure why the author left that proof as an exercise if it was already proven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is mostly superfluous, since it does effectively follow by a symmetric argument. You have that $[a] \subseteq [b]$ for all pairs $(a,b) \in R$. Taking the ordered pair $(a',b') := (b,a)$ will then have $[a'] = [b] \subseteq [a] = [b']$. But we can always go from a more axiomatic perspective, as you and your text did. (And there's no harm in fully justifying things.)

This would be a more basic set-inclusion proof though, and I think you overcomplicate matters just a bit. Here's how I would do it... Assume $aRb$; thus $bRa$ by symmetry. We want to show $[b] \subseteq [a]$, i.e. $\forall x \in [b]$, it follows $x \in [a]$. Observe:

\begin{align*}
x \in [b]
&\iff xRb \tag{def.} \\
&\implies xRa \tag{transitivity} \\
&\iff x \in [a]\tag{def.} 
\end{align*}

- The first is just definition of membership of an equivalence class represented by $b$
- The second is transitivity applied to the facts that $xRb$ and $bRa$
- The third is again definition of membership of equivalence classes

Thus, $[b] \subseteq [a]$.

---

*...granted, this question is quite old, so I imagine you don't need help now. But hopefully this helps someone in the future, and, if nothing else, gets this question out of the unanswered queue.*